# Binding a Stepper with a Dictionary SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm not sure if this is possible but I'm currently trying to create a list of steppers using a dictionary[String: Int]. Using the stepper I'm hoping to change the qty amount in the dictionary. I tried binding the value to the stepper by first doing $basic[name] and then that didn't work and so I ended up with $basic[keyPath: name] which resulted in fewer errors but still wasn't working. In the beginning I was having problems of not wanting to change the order of the dictionary that I made, and so I ended up with the ForEach below which worked for not changing the order of dictionary, however, I'm wondering if that's one of the reasons that the binding isn't working.

```
    import SwiftUI
    
    struct AllSuppliesStruct {
        @State var basic = ["Regular Staples": 0, "Big Staples": 0]
    
    
        var body: some View {
            Form {
                //Basic Supplies
                ForEach(basic.sorted(by: >), id: \.key) { name, qty in
                    Stepper("\(name), \(qty)", value: $basic[keyPath: name], in: 0...10)
                           }
            }
        }
    }
```

Goal:
If I pressed on the stepper only once for both Regular and Big Staples then I expect this in the dictionary

```
basic = ["Regular Staples": 1, "Big Staples": 1]
```

Comment: Create a model instead of using a dictionary, it will be much more stable and less prone to bugs

Comment: Remember that dictionaries are *unordered*, so any order you see when running your code is subject to change anyway

Comment: @loremipsum do you think custom Binding work? Or do you think I will only run into issues?

Comment: It can work, as long as you account for everything. Any forcing, or ignoring of issues will inevitably have troublesome bugs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can manually create a `Binding` that acts on `basic` and pass that to `Stepper`:

```
struct AllSuppliesStruct: View {
  @State var basic = ["Regular Staples": 0, "Big Staples": 0]

  var body: some View {
    Form {
      ForEach(basic.sorted(by: >), id: \.key) { name, qty in
        Stepper(
          "\(name), \(qty)",
          value: .init(
            get: { basic[name]! },
            set: { basic[name] = $0 }
          ),
          in: 0...10
        )
      }
    }
  }
}
```